# Typescript generics: checking a unique property on a generic type object in if condition doesn't determine the object's type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Typing `postMessage` communication in my web app and currently stuck with trying to write Typescript types for `window.addEventListener` listeners.

I have a list of possible messages my listeners can receive and I distinguish them by `event.data.method` property. However with the types I wrote I'm not able to determine the rest of the `event.data` content. Am I missing some type guards or my generics are just wrong? Thank you.

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgc08gbwChlTkBybATwFoALYcgLkJLPZyggjFBxYxgofANxtSAXzHtKcWgCMqEZq3bt4XAO4QANjoFDR45FKISiRMFQAOKdFlwQAMsEEQQ0ZAF5kAHlTIEAAekCAAJhjIANYQVAD2MGiY2HgYAHwAFMYQLPYpEACiAG7uYL7EamQAtjx0cWG50pXIYXBgcLnJjhgA2qgAuk2SaQA0RACU3mnIcCBUYkQIcSCCM2FheY7FpS5uHlDeyBk6rqHQnQ54u2dQ4yxFccBhU8aaoGFxmgB0cOvb4Nd3NAMuQapdlCNkCc9tBxgtfhsunh-mBAfsMhASuApqoyMBEhisWAvq12l8amA6s8vDSKNR6IxJhVmgB6FnIAAS0BQAElkJo4gBXHTPYK2BBgZCUtrIHnkPTIeQoODyHQoMBxZCCjAoABEmNKJLacCNZM43F4IBwush8kFkr5eDATGM7DZyAAClA4rYoFYKOaeHxyC04vgQHFJcFTshllKbChyARkIHLfxkIJhFaRCZkAAfQjIDQQbR6AxZnA5iTkL6usjur0+6D+8ip4Oh8ORwJBGNxqy2CjJ4ul-QZwzZkw1jIAJgAzLOAJzjOukJYrOJqr46OI4QmG0kmg9fNtWuHGcwSOFAA)

```js
interface Messages {
    'say-hi': {
        greeting: string;
    };
    'say-bye': {
        farewell: string;
    };
}

type MessageListener = <M extends keyof Messages>(
    e: MessageEvent<{
        method: M;
        data: Messages[M];
    }>,
) => any;

const addMessageEventListener = (listener: MessageListener): void =>
    window.addEventListener('message', listener);

addMessageEventListener(event => {
    if (event.data.method === 'say-hi') {
        // Here I would expect that I'll be able to use "event.data.data.greeting", but I get:
        // Property 'greeting' does not exist on type '{ greeting: string; } | { farewell: string; }'.
        // Property 'greeting' does not exist on type '{ farewell: string; }'.(2339)
        console.log(event.data.data.greeting);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics will get you in trouble here. If you never statically provide a type for a generic type parameter, then you don't need a generic. And here `M` never gets populated by anything because the argument `e` will never have any other type besides the union of possible event types.

What you really want is a discriminated union of possible message types.

You can derive that union from `Messages` with a mapped type, like so:

```
type MyMessageEvent = {
    [K in keyof Messages]: MessageEvent<{
        method: K,
        data: Messages[K]
    }>
}[keyof Messages]
```

Which is equivalent to this, but will update if you change the `Messages` type.

```
type MyMessageEvent =
  | MessageEvent<{
      method: 'say-hi'
      data: { greeting: string }
    }>
  | MessageEvent<{
      method: 'say-bye'
      data: { farewell: string }
    }>
```

This is now a discriminated union, where the discriminant `method` allows you to narrow the type to just one of those union members.

And now you simply use that type like any other with no generics.

```
type MessageListener = (e: MyMessageEvent) => any;

const addMessageEventListener = (listener: MessageListener): void =>
    window.addEventListener('message', listener);

addMessageEventListener(event => {
    if (event.data.method === 'say-hi') {
        console.log(event.data.data.greeting); // works
    }
});
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgc08gbwChlTkBybATwFoALYcgLkJLPZyggjFBxYxgofANxtSAXzHtKcWgCMqEZq3bt4XAO4QANjoFDR45FKISiRMFQAOKVFXRZcEAKIA3COGQBeVWQDaANLIoMgA1hBUAPYwaJjYeBgAuiyOCa4e4AA8xGpkALY8dFEAJiyBADTG7CVwYHCp8c4YQUnGEgB8Zv4R0bFpzW2WNnZNeAAywIKe0D7IABQQqQ5jGZ5gAJQ+HchwIFRiRAhRIIK7JSUDeO7rk9Mgs77zOlOQD1CNThOvM1AbLG4osASttjJpQCUopoAHRwC43cB3N7QebkQpfZQVZAve7QDaHOGXVYIsBI36LTJgbZ+UjAWIU9bQ2r1aGFMDFEHeLkUaj0RhbXJ5ZDHU5RHQQaE6KI4BngJl1ODylmcbi8EA4fHIAD0WuQmiiUDCGHaZnxQA)

Comment: A similar alternative allows you to be more specific if you want: https://tsplay.dev/W4nkBN

Answer (score 1):

I would use a more straightforward type definition personally:

```js
type Messages = { method: 'say-hi', data: {greeting: string} } 
                | { method: 'say-bye', data: {farewell: string} }

type MessageListener = ( e: MessageEvent<Messages> ) => any;

const addMessageEventListener = (listener: MessageListener): void =>
    window.addEventListener('message', listener);

addMessageEventListener(event => {
    if (event.data.method === 'say-hi') {
        console.log(event.data.data.greeting); // ok
    }
});
```

Unless there's a reason to structure it the way you did, this seems simpler.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzBUC8UDeBbCwAFgPYAmAXFAOTIgC0hAllQDRSlLBKXYoBOEAowB2KSvGB8RKAL5Q5AKCjKVqtVAA%20OfETKUaSegCMQEVu07ccAMyQCA7hAA2T8ZOlyZChaEiwEyGgAMowSEMIQfJhQABRKKhCUcIioEACiAG7hwAA8yYEIAHwsCgCUmIVQSMIgANzeAMbEwhJVpKT5qZnZIWERUVgxTqHA4ZFJAam9o-2llBnEjKQV8cr2IqTE9gB0SO3dwsDTY3wxVPgpaObDfZGl9Qp7HZNoB0cjJzEQWYcVOKtQRjWWLfbLbDhcbY6EjLDBw6i0BjMcrYAGqJotYhOCDbJzEFBfH7AcGWEmQ-iCYDSe4Arwye5AA)